# Move Files containing a String without having to randomly generate the Filepath

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I'm using the ERP BEXT. BEXT generates 4 kind of files, which have to be imported on a server. All file names contain a special 11 character code as seen in the image below.

An example of the 4 kind of files:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQhy6.png]

Before importing, the files. I need to check if the 4 file exist with the same special 11 character.
That's what I've done I'm storing the special 11 character code in a .txt files.

That's the first step and it's working fine.
At the moment, I'm storing the codes in a table of String.
The current problem that I'm facing is that I have to randomly generate the filepath of the file.
It's working fine, but not how I want to. A few errors occur, that's why I want to optimized it.

I've tried using try and catch the exception, and avoid error, but it's not clean. And the program crashes sometimes.

```
string ID = File.ReadAllText(@"\\srv-bext\import-bext\acontrol.txt");
                string prefix1 = "exp_vente_ent_";
                string prefix3 = "exp_vente_lig_";
                string prefix5 = "rcp_achat_ent_";
                string prefix6 = "rcp_achat_lig_";
                string prefix7 = "rec_vente_lig_";
                string prefix8 = "rec_vente_ent_";
                string a = ".txt";
                string b = ".top";
                String root = @"\\srv-bext\import-bext\";
                String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"\\srv-bext\import-bext\acontrol.txt");

                for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //génération de filepath ciblé, pour trouver les bons et bouger les fichiers
                        string fullPath0 = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix1 + lines[i] + a);
                        string fullPath0a = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix1 + lines[i] + b);
                        string fullPath2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix3 + lines[i] + a);
                        string fullPath2a = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix3 + lines[i] + b);
                        string fullPath4 = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix5 + lines[i] + a);
                        string fullPath4a = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix5 + lines[i] + b);
                        string fullPath5 = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix6 + lines[i] + a);
                        string fullPath5a = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix6 + lines[i] + b);
                        string fullPath6 = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix7 + lines[i] + a);
                        string fullPath6a = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix7 + lines[i] + b);
                        string fullPath7 = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix8 + lines[i] + a);
                        string fullPath7a = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, prefix8 + lines[i] + b);



                        if (File.Exists(fullPath0))
                        {
                            try
                            {


                                File.Copy(fullPath0, @"\\srv-bext\ARCHIVES-PROD\" + fullPath0.Substring(23, 29));
                                File.Move(fullPath0, @"\\vm-erp-sql\Interfaces_BEXT\PROD\Import\" + fullPath0.Substring(23, 29));

                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Checked");
                            }
                        }

                        if (File.Exists(fullPath0a))

                        {

                            try
                            {

                                File.Copy(fullPath0a, @"\\srv-bext\ARCHIVES-PROD\" + fullPath0a.Substring(23, 29));
                                File.Move(fullPath0a, @"\\vm-erp-sql\Interfaces_BEXT\PROD\Import\" + fullPath0a.Substring(23, 29));



                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Not done");
                            }
```

I just want to move the files which contains the 11 character code without having to randomly generate the filepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something more simple:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input_dir = @"env\srv-bext\import-bext\";
        string output_dir = @"env\srv-bext\import-bext\imported\";
        string archive_dir = @"env\srv-bext\import-bext\archive\";
        string[] index = File.ReadAllLines(input_dir + "acontrol.txt");
        string[] prefixes = new string[] {
            "exp_vente_ent_",
            "ctl_",
            "exp_vente_lig_",
            "mvt_",
            "rcp_achat_ent_",
            "rcp_achat_lig_",
            "rec_vente_lig_",
            "rec_vente_ent_"
        };
        string[] extensions = new string[2] {"txt", "top" };

        if (!Directory.Exists(input_dir))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Err: Input directory doesn't exist.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(output_dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(output_dir);
        if (!Directory.Exists(archive_dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(archive_dir);

        foreach (string id  in index)
        {
            foreach (string pre in prefixes)
            {
                foreach (string ext in extensions)
                {
                    string filename = pre + id + "." + ext;

                    if (File.Exists(input_dir + filename))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            File.Copy(input_dir + filename, output_dir + filename);
                            File.Copy(input_dir + filename, archive_dir + filename);
                            File.Delete(input_dir + filename);
                            Console.WriteLine("Info: " + filename + " file processed");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Err: " + e.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Warn: " + filename + " is missing");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```